# Strange issues with assembled PC

Tags: desktop-computer

This is my first assembled PC, I have replaced some components on other existing PCs/laptops so was not that hard. The PC worked ok for a week but now something strange is happening. Configuration:

- [PSU EVGA 600W](https://www.cyberpuerta.mx/Computo-Hardware/Componentes/Fuentes-de-Poder-para-PC-s/Fuente-de-Poder-EVGA-0600-K1-80-PLUS-Bronze-24-pin-ATX-120mm-600W.html)
- [GPU GTX 1650](https://www.cyberpuerta.mx/index.php?cl=details&anid=9d72a0d5abd899ca27017a7ab34c3ede)
- [MB Aorus B450 Pro WiFi](https://www.cyberpuerta.mx/Computo-Hardware/Componentes/Tarjetas-Madre/Tarjeta-Madre-AORUS-B450-AORUS-PRO-WIFI-S-AM4-AMD-B450-HDMI-64GB-DDR4-para-AMD.html)
- [AMD Ryzen 5 3600](https://www.cyberpuerta.mx/Computo-Hardware/Componentes/Procesadores/Procesadores-para-PC/Procesador-AMD-Ryzen-5-3600-S-AM4-3-60GHz-32MB-L3-Cache-con-Disipador-Wraith-Stealth.html)
- [32GB Ram](https://www.cyberpuerta.mx/Computo-Hardware/Memorias-RAM-Flash/Memorias-RAM-para-PC/Memoria-RAM-HyperX-FURY-Black-DDR4-2666MHz-16GB-Non-ECC-CL16-XMP.html)
- [SSD M2 XPG S11 Pro](https://www.cyberpuerta.mx/index.php?cl=details&anid=1d6b758b557a63e0384ea4f9e02b9004)
- [Thermaltake H200 TG RGB Case](https://www.cyberpuerta.mx/index.php?cl=details&anid=7780ebeec41e6cd751f9dc30371b7bc2) (it has RGB lights with color changing transition)

Five days ago while I was working the monitor went black and the RGB stopped (color changing transition freezed, lights still on), I restarted the PC and everything normal.

Next day, after 1-5 minutes from boot, again video was lost and the RGB stopped. I restarted several times but same thing, even after entering the BIOS without touching anything 1-5 minutes video gone. Disconnected from main power supply, waited 5 minutes, turn on and everything working ok again apparently.

Yesterday, I turned it on and there was no video from the begining, RGB freezed. I started to worry/frustrate. Disconnecting from main didnt work. The HDD LED blinks, so it is actually booting. I connected the PC to my TV and there is video! RGB lights still freeze but there is video showing windows login. Plug off TV, turn off, plug in monitor, turn on, no video/RGB freezed. Turn of, plug off monitor, turn on, still RGB lights freezed. I connected the same monitor to old PC and it's working fine.

The RGB lights of the case are sharing power cable from PSU with and 2.5" HDD, unplug RGB and plug with second cable from PSU, no sharing. PC worked ok again, I got video and RGB lights are moving.

Today again! No video and RGB freezed from begining. Plug to the TV and there is video, RGB lights still freezed, after some minutes RGB lights start moving. Still on, unplug from TV and plug to monitor. There is video. Restart. There is video and RGB lights moving. What is happening?

Motherboard malfunction? How is related the video card and RGB lights? Why RGB lights stop when video is gone? PSU Malfunction? Looks like the PC runs ok even if there is no video and RGB is stopped.

This is frustrating and time consuming. My work is stopped.

**Edit:**

Last friday computer didnt turn on, I disassembled PSU from case and tested pines, voltages were above normal (3.3 > 5.5, -12 > 8, 5 > 8), after minutes they went to normal, after some more minutes they were lower normal. I'm blaming the PSU by its erratic behaviour, but not sure until get a replacement. I hope my MB has not damaged.

Comment: Uninstall the RGB control drivers and software to see if the problem stops.

Comment: I don't have software installed for the RGB lights, an with BIOS (no SO loaded) was happening the same.

Comment: It might be a hardware problem bad connection or you should try uninstalling, replacing or updating the drivers. Use a live Linux USB in order to check if the issue will occur. If it does not, then you have a software problem.